# Evento Leave en C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Buenas tardes compañeros, tengo un problema con este evento, en el mismo de acuerdo a muchas variables debo colocar el foco a distintos controles, dependiendo de algunos resultados de Base de datos y no encuentro como hacerlo sin caer en un loop.
Mi rutina en el evento Leave es:

```
private void cmbTaxType_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtLevyYear.Text == "" || txtBillNo.Text == "")
            return;
        if (EKey != null)
            EKey.Dispose();
        EKey = ObjShow.TShowTbl("SELECT * FROM tblExKey WHERE Ex_Key_Levy_Year='" + txtLevyYear.Text + 
            "' And Ex_Key_Tax_Type='" + cmbTaxType.Text + "'");
        tRec = EKey.Rows.Count;                             // Total Records
        rEkey = EKey.Rows[nLin];                            // Record position
        txtBillNo.Text = rEkey["Ex_Key_Bill_No"].ToString();
        if (CameFromExciseBatch)
        {
            LoadBatchData();
            return;
        }
        GetExcise();
        if (!ExciseOn)
        {
            if (bNewBill)
            {
                ClearRestFields();
                FillZeros();
                SetDefault();
                TownDefault();
                if (CameFromExciseBatch)
                    BatchData2();
                txtCommit.Select();
            }
            else
            {
                FillZeros();
                if (CameFromExciseBatch)
                {
                    BatchData2();
                    txtBillNo.Select();
                }
            }
            if (bFocus)
            {
                bFocus = false;
                btnProc.Select();
            }
            if (bCorp)
            {
                bCorp = false;
                txtCorpName.Select();
            }
        }
        if (!Convert.ToBoolean(rExc["Ex_Bill_Transfered"]))
            btnProc.Select();
        if (MoveToTown)
            cmbNewTown.Select();
    }
```

Como se puede observar hay una rutina (GetExcise) que regresa las variables de acuerdo al control que obtendrá el foco así como hay validaciones de campos de Base de datos (rExc["Ex_Bill_Transfered"]) que tambien iniden en esto.
Pero como Leave no es exactamente un 'LostFocus' cuando hago un Select() de cualquier control se reinicia esta rutina y hace un loop.
Cualquier idea o ayuda para resolver esto será bienvenida. Gracias

Comment: Como primera recomendación diría que debería parametizar las consultas sql: https://aprendizdesysadmin.com/parametrizacion-de-las-consultas/.  Por otro lado me parece que lo que usted necesita es un switch-case para manejar los resultados.

Comment: Agradezco tu comentario Richard, pero esto es una programación por capas y la capa de Negocios está ya establecida, si analizas verás que se usan objetos (creados en a capa de negocio) para ejecutar el query. Lo del Swich no resolvería el problema ya que caería en la misma situación (estoy dentro del Leave) de que al colocar el foco a otro control se hace un nuevo llamado a leave donde me encuentro (loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez alguno del los participantes de este gran sitio de ayuda se encuentren en este tipo de inconveniente. Encontré una solución (Tal vez no la mejor pero funciona):
Lo primero es crear una rutina de la siguiente forma:

```
private void *NombreControl*_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Acá colocas todos los focos a distintos controles de acuerdo a las
    // variables (ver mi código)
}
```

Y en la forma de pantalla despues del InitializeComponet colocar:

*NombreControl*.LostFocus += new EventHandler(this.*NombreControl*_LostFocus);

En el evento Leave puedes tener algunas verificaciones, pero el LostFocus se ejecutará y colocará el foco al control correspondiente.
Y eso es todo